# Gnuplot with gnuplot-iostream and X and Y axis

Tags: gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

When I use gnuplot with a simple file at C:\gnu\test.txt containing

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
11 121
12 144
```

I get the graph I expected after starting `gnuplot` from the command line and running.

```
plot 'C:\gnu\test.txt' with lines
```

So this works fine.

I would like to be able to do this using `gnuplot-iostream` where I can have control of what is on the X and Y axis.

Something roughly along the lines of

```
Gnuplot gp; 

gp << "plot 'C:\\gnu\\test.txt' using 1:2 with lines";
```

or

```
gp << "plot '-' using 1:2 with lines";

gp.send1d(data with x and y axis);
```

If you catch my drift.

I really do not understand what appears to me to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add an end-line character at the end of your commands, eg:

```cpp
gp << "plot 'C:\\gnu\\test.txt' using 1:2 with lines\n";
```

For further readings, there is the [documentation](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream/wiki/BasicUsage)

Comment: Thank you. Adding a \n newline at the end of the command had no effect although I do agree it is necessary.

The documentation in the link is horrible. There is no explanation as to what

 gp << "plot" << gp.file1d(data, "filename.dat") << "with points\n"; even means.